# ERROR: No existe ningún constructor para una clase

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++11, visual-c++

recién estoy comenzando con los temas de programación orientado a objetos y estoy teniendo algunos problemas. He implementado este código pero cuando compilo muestra el error de que no hay un constructor para la clase Ajedrecista. Estoy aplicando el tema de relaciones entre clases (unidireccionales).

```
class Ajedrecista
{
private:
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;
    std::string sexo;
    std::string pais;
public:
    Ajedrecista(std::string name ,int edadd, std::string sexxo,  std::string paiss ){ //Constructor de la clase Ajedrecista
        nombre = name;
        edad = edadd;
        sexo = sexxo;
        pais = paiss;
    }
    ~Ajedrecista(){}
    void mostrar(){
        std::cout<<"Nombre : "<<nombre<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Edad : "<<edad<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Sexo : "<<sexo<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Pais : "<<pais<<std::endl;
    }
};



class CampeonatoAjedrez
{
private:
    std::string fechaIni;
    std::string fechaFin;
    int nroEnfrentamientos;
    std::string enfrentamientos [3][2];
    Ajedrecista nrojugadores[3];
public:
    CampeonatoAjedrez(std::string ini , std::string fin, int nro , std::string enfrent[3][2], Ajedrecista nrojug[]){ // Error
        fechaIni = ini;
        fechaFin = fin;
        nroEnfrentamientos = nro;
        enfrentamientos[3][2] = enfrent[3][2];
        nrojugadores[3] = nrojug[3];

    }
    ~CampeonatoAjedrez(){}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

En la línea:

```
Ajedrecista nrojugadores[3];
```

Se crea un arreglo y llama al constructor por defecto para cada posición del arreglo.

C++ asigna un [constructor por defecto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) a tu clase a menos que hayas declarado otro constructor. Por eso obtienes ese error.

La solución es agregar un constructor por defecto explícitamente:

```
public:
    // Constructor por defecto 
    Ajedrecista(){
    }

    Ajedrecista(std::string name ,int edadd, std::string sexxo,  std::string paiss ){
        nombre = name;
        edad = edadd;
        sexo = sexxo;
        pais = paiss;
    }
```

---

También noté que asignas arreglos a arreglos. Por ejemplo, en las líneas:

```
enfrentamientos[3][2] = enfrent[3][2];
nrojugadores[3] = nrojug[3];
```

En C y en C++ no puedes hacer eso. En el caso de que se pudiera, estarías asignando una copia.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es asignar los elementos del arreglo individualmente.

Los [`array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) de la [librería de contenedores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Sequence_containers) sí pueden ser asignados de la manera que pretendes.

Answer (score 1):

En C++ los constructores (y otras funciones de clase concretas) tienen un tratamiento especial; este tratamiento es que el compilador crea el constructor por defecto automáticamente, por eso este código funciona:

```
class Pato {};

Pato p;
```

Como puedes ver, la clase `Pato` está vacía: no tiene ni siquiera constructor y aún así se ha podido crear la instancia `p`. Esto se debe a que el compilador ha creado el…

###### Constructor por defecto.

El constructor por defecto de un objeto, es el constructor que no tiene parámetros para construir dicho objeto, en el ejemplo de `Pato p` vemos que la instancia `p` no ha recibido nada para ser construida; es decir: se ha llamado el **Constructor por defecto** definido por el compilador; puedes simular la creación del constructor por defecto del compilador así:

```
class Pato
{
    Pato() = default;
};
```

En el código anterior, añadir `default` al constructor no indica que ese sea el constructor por defecto si no que se generará la implementación por defecto, es decir: se generará la implementación del compilador.

El constructor por defecto generado por el compilador deja de existir si definimos un constructor manualmente:

```
class Pato
{
public:
    Pato(int patas) {}
};

Pato p; // Error: no existe ningún constructor para 'Pato' que coincida con los argumentos
```

En el ejemplo al definir un constructor para `Pato`, el compilador ha dejado de generar el constructor por defecto y ahora cree que la **única** manera de construir un `Pato` es llamando a `Pato(int)`, pero como no le hemos pasado nada al constructor muestra el error.

---

El constructor por defecto se llama al construir un objeto sin pasarle parámetros, esto sucede (como ya hemos visto) al crear una instancia directamente o cuando el objeto forma parte de una formación<sup>1</sup>:

```
Pato p;        // Constructor por defecto para la instancia 'p'.
Pato patos[3]; // Constructor por defecto para 'patos[0]', 'patos[1]' y 'patos[2]'.
```

Si el constructor por defecto no ha sido generado (ni por nosotros ni por el compilador) el código anterior sería erróneo, en tu caso sucede al crear una formación de `Ajedrecista` como parte de otra clase:

```
class CampeonatoAjedrez
{
private:
    std::string fechaIni;
    std::string fechaFin;
    int nroEnfrentamientos;
    std::string enfrentamientos [3][2];
    // Constructor por defecto para 'nrojugadores[0]', 'nrojugadores[1]' y 'nrojugadores[2]'.
    Ajedrecista nrojugadores[3];
```

El motivo por el que esto sucede es algo complejo, tiene que ver con el…

###### Ciclo de vida de los sub-objetos.

En un objeto C++, los sub-objetos que lo componen empiezan a existir desde que el objeto se construye hasta que el objeto se destruye, tomando como ejemplo tu  `CampeonatoAjedrez` voy a marcar cuando empiezan a existir sus sub-objetos:

```
    CampeonatoAjedrez(std::string ini , std::string fin, int nro , std::string enfrent[3][2], Ajedrecista nrojug[])
//  AQUÍ los sub-objetos de 'CampeonatoAjedrez' empiezan a existir
    {
        /* Una vez en el cuerpo del constructor, los sub-objetos de
           CampeonatoAjedrez ya existen, por eso puedes asignarles valores. */
        fechaIni = ini;
        fechaFin = fin;
        nroEnfrentamientos = nro;
        enfrentamientos[3][2] = enfrent[3][2];
        nrojugadores[3] = nrojug[3];
    }
```

Si te fijas, los sub-objetos empiezan a existir **ANTES** de entrar en el cuerpo del constructor de `CampeonatoAjedrez`, por lo tanto en ese punto se llaman sus constructores por defecto y `Ajedrecista` al carecer de uno, falla. Para arreglar este error te sugiero los siguientes cambios:

```
class CampeonatoAjedrez
{
public:
    // Definimos por comodidad unos tipos en base a contenedores estándar
    using fila = std::array<std::string, 3>;
    using tabla = std::array<fila, 3>;
    using competidores = std::array<Ajedrecista, 3>;

    CampeonatoAjedrez(std::string ini, std::string fin, int nro, const tabla &enfrent, const competidores &nrojug) :
    /* Llamamos al constructor de COPIA/movimiento de los objetos
       cuando estos empiezan a existir. */
        fechaIni(std::move(ini)),
        fechaFin(std::move(fin)),
        nroEnfrentamientos(nro),
        enfrentamientos(enfrent),
        nrojugadores(nrojug)
    {
        /* Ahora el constructor está vacío porque todo el trabajo
           se ha hecho antes de entrar aquí. */
    }
    ~CampeonatoAjedrez() = default; // Que el compilador cree el destructor.
private:
    std::string fechaIni;
    std::string fechaFin;
    int nroEnfrentamientos;

    tabla enfrentamientos;

    competidores nrojugadores;
};
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVThTttADP6dPIWVSYiijI7xZyIFiTEmIU0b057ATdz2quQuXC4Vo@reZQ/AU/BgzL5LRNMy/ri9zz77@2xf8rp@n5eo58/vlM7LtiCYKNM4S1hdxC8YWou/twEOUXp@8cyXmwYul1RYylXjMF7HtVUrdHQWR40rzs5CKGhTTS1lcaS0AyqwyIb@hu7NDlSjarK4bqelyjnbVpXDQWasCNI@bZHCTtp7kwLs5m1gtIbx@MpoBtvcGQusq0QQRTRQFEWBO5z7UkwykkJ89PXkLOT57IvJWSrw2Rfi8yaO/myzH60ZWRlVQCXNRsuIZBGOuWndZJJ8DyXPIJlMQvnJxPtJF2W2E3wtdHyoMHoj8Jfw9IHC@I3AWxHgA0XDMHATb7I4DpO/wqomo9GZoO9B5t8PbDyGLzRTWrFKqLnDualMoYRsqxlyqmZLGqbScm690Y40FcYSw417@qsLtHHUNjK1meLpnIdB@n2cbM00hdOLrI90ON0NlcuDGKZSk1Oh1iB0a1DhRhztqRzsHwsc7hxLTkH2UVtevVxWrON0QHpmSbseHbA44PBlOx@BtO4IvpVYoXQOyxD9sqZXP25vLseVWalKcTbjV5cjzXRJzjQ8y7xFXRhponS4qhU9oOYW0z3rUvYYjsYcNaN8gTdaBTmcjw5ZzGiU9r6vSm/5WFfwMdHrIAQDgeaQIe@iHbw799dYH3q1h53YOJLNZ7mXC2OZ31CrXwJYYf70aGSD7loCZ0RYCfxuprg0fJufHywQFszYAPIONdIQrsovC/CufXoMeuUZ7o9yxOMvaIZt6TL@IsBPruFpcNdKIQu5JQ8V1BM7/s9Hrm9o9grMvey@fvvtkyULG0L7jsGSbPcw8w9RMlbIgxrx2@u2W75TTY05hb0slSOLZfPqLkMuE0hOEhlR8tH/nIpZC842wSSFZComTzabtEMLAUjMbAudC7AQozo02C5Zcsmuk0/slj9suovJ5x6XP2x6/KrH5Q@bjc/IsxQtllxrNXzgRjw//wM)</kbd>.

Te animo a crear nuevas preguntas si quieres más detalles sobre lo que puedes haber aprendido en estas respuestas.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.