"[Error] no matching function for call to " C++
Necesito hacer un un programa usando clases para realizar las ventas de una serie de productos (en este caso 3) y determina el producto mas costoso, el mas vendido y el monto de las ventas. Hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo es lo que esta abajo:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class Producto {
public:
    string nombre;
    double precio;
    int cantidadVendida;

    Producto(string n, double p) : nombre(n), precio(p), cantidadVendida(0) {}
};

class Ventas {
private:
Producto productos[3];
double totalVentas;

public:
Ventas(): totalVentas(0.0){
    productos[0] = Producto("Producto A", 10.0);
    productos[1] = Producto("Producto B", 20.0);
    productos[2] = Producto("Producto C", 30.0);        
}

void realizarVenta(int productoIndex, int cantidad) {
    if (productoIndex < 0 || productoIndex >= 3 || cantidad < 0) {
        cout << "Índice de producto inválido o cantidad negativa." << endl;
        return;
    }
    productos[productoIndex].cantidadVendida += cantidad;
    totalVentas += productos[productoIndex].precio * cantidad;
}

void mostrarResultados() {
    int masVendidoIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
        if (productos[i].cantidadVendida > productos[masVendidoIndex].cantidadVendida){
            masVendidoIndex = i;
        }
    }

    int masCostosoIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
        if (productos[i].precio > productos[masCostosoIndex].precio) {
            masCostosoIndex = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Monto total de ventas: $" << totalVentas << endl;
    cout << "Producto más vendido: " << productos[masVendidoIndex].nombre << " (Cantidad: " << productos[masVendidoIndex].cantidadVendida << ")" << endl;
    cout << "Producto más costoso: " << productos[masCostosoIndex].nombre << " (Precio: $" << productos[masCostosoIndex].precio << ")" << endl;
}
};

int main() {
Ventas ventas;

// Realizar algunas ventas
ventas.realizarVenta(0, 5); // Vender 5 unidades del Producto A
ventas.realizarVenta(1, 3); // Vender 3 unidades del Producto B
ventas.realizarVenta(2, 2); // Vender 2 unidades del Producto C
ventas.realizarVenta(1, 4); // Vender 4 unidades del Producto B

// Mostrar resultados
ventas.mostrarResultados();

return 0;
}

El problema es que no importa lo que intente no me deja compilar el programa pues continua diciendome que:
24    27  D:\Programa IV\ventasProducto.cpp   [Error] no matching function for call to 'Producto::Producto()
Ese seria mi principal problema. Alguno aqui podria mostrarme como se hace para poder corregirlo

Al declarar Producto productos[3]; te falto inicializarlo. El compilador intento inicializarlo sin argumentos llamando Producto::Producto(). Como ese método no existe, te reclama. Una solución sería trasladar la inicialización que haces en Ventas() a la declaración.

Tal vez esto te sea de ayuda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/585361/2742

El problema es que no estás viendo el error completo:
.code.tio.cpp: In constructor ‘Ventas::Ventas()’:
.code.tio.cpp:22:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘Producto::Producto()’
 Ventas(): totalVentas(0.0){
                          ^

Cuando se ejecuta el constructor de una clase, se llama el constructor por defecto para cada miembro. En este caso la clase Producto no tiene constructor por defecto (sin parámetros) y por eso obtienes error, como dijo Candid Moe.
El momento correcto para llamar el constructor es inmediatamente después del miembro. Así:
Producto productos[3] = { {"Producto A", 10.0}, {"Producto B", 20.0}, {"Producto C", 30.0} };

O más explícitamente:
Producto productos[3] = { Producto("Producto A", 10.0), Producto("Producto B", 20.0), Producto("Producto C", 30.0) };

O en la lista de inicialización de miembros de la clase Ventas:
Ventas(...) : totalVentas(0.0), productos{ {"Producto A", 10.0}, {"Producto B", 20.0}, {"Producto C", 30.0} } {}

También puedes hacerlo más explícitamente como antes.
Lo importante es que la inicialización del objeto en sí ocurre después que la de los miembros.

Ok entiendo. Gracias por aclararlo
